# How to open the same file twice

Tags: appcode

I wonder how to open the same source file twice, meaning in 2 editors side by side?

When I have the first editor opened, pull the file on another editor window, I'll be sent to the 'old' window (I've just opened) and I can not open the same file twice.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: It's possible only in the split mode (split editor horizontally or vertically).

Comment: That was the missing bit, thanks! Make it an answer, and I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splitting the editor (from the tab context menu) allows to have 2 copies of the same file open at the same time.